# Getting the val of td in same tr jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering how i could console.log the value of

```
$('<td>').text(result[i].id),
```

field if I call the function on the input button:

```
$('<tr>').append(
            $('<td>').text(result[i].id),
            $('<td>').text(result[i].naam),
            $('<td>').text(result[i].brouwer),
            $($('<input onclick="getAllData(this)" type="button" value="View" />'))
        ).appendTo('#output');
```

Comment: console.log($("tr").children("td:first").text());

Comment: Check out the https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/ and https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/ in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following code:

```
getAllData = function(a) {
  console.log(a.parentElement.firstChild.textContent);
}

result=[{'id': 1, 'naam': 'foo', 'brouwer': 'bar'}];
result.forEach(function( r, i, result ) {
    $('<tr>').append(
                     $('<td>').text(result[i].id),
                     $('<td>').text(result[i].naam),
                     $('<td>').text(result[i].brouwer),
                     $($('<input onclick="getAllData(this);" type="button" value="View" />'))
                    ).appendTo('#output');
});
```

And a table like so:

```
<table id='output'>
  <tr></tr>
</table>
```

you'll get what you're looking for.

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kp88myqr/15/) for the working example.